# Read after Write Latency in Asynchronous FIFO?

Tags: verilog, fpga, fifo, xilinx-ise

I am trying to interface a module with  an asynchronous FIFO generated by the Xilinx CORE Generator. However, I have observed that the data supplied at the input port of AFIFO (although correct) starts appearing on dout after a latency of 6-7 clock cycles. Is this to be expected? Or am I doing something wrong? What I am doing is that assert the write_enable pin of AFIFO, supply the input data and then assert the read_enable pin at the next cycle. But still the problem of latency exists. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I am attaching a part of my code.

```
always @ (posedge clk1, posedge rst)//faster clock domain
begin
    if (rst)
        wr_en<= 1'b 0;

    else
        begin
            if (data_wrt)
                begin
                wr_en<= 1'b 1;                          
                end
            else
                wr_en<= 1'b 0;
        end
end
always @ (negedge clk2, posedge rst)//slower clock domain
    begin
        if (rst)
            rd_en<= 1'b 0;

        else
            begin
                if (wr_en)
                    begin
                    rd_en<= 1'b 1;                              
                    end
                else
                    rd_en<= 1'b 0;              
            end

    end
AFIFO AFIFO1(//AFIFO module instantiation
    .din(data_in),
    .rd_clk(clk2),
    .rd_en(rd_en),
    .rst(reset),
    .wr_clk(clk1),
    .wr_en(wr_en),
    .dout(data_out),
    .empty(empty),
    .full(full)
    );
```

[image: AFIFO Input Output]

[image: AFIFO2]

Comment: any code fragment?

Comment: If your `clk2`  is slower than `clk1` your `rd_en` flip flop might be missing some of the enable signals (in the `if(wr_en)` block).

Comment: Then what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

What is the clock relationship? Assuming that you are seeing the latency in 6-7 clk1 (fast clock) cycles, that does seem like something you would expect depending on the clock relationship clk1/clk2.

That said, the point of an asynchronous FIFO is usually to act as a synchroniser from one clock domain to another. The writing clock domain (clk1) will write data to the AFIFO as long as it is not full. The reading clock domain (clk2) will read new data as long as the AFIFO is not empty. What you are doing here is breaking this usage.

You are using `wr_en` which is generated by clk1 to control `rd_en` which is clocked by clk2. So now `wr_en` is used in both clock domains and will cause [metastability](http://www.asic-world.com/tidbits/metastablity.html).

So in short, you are not using AFIFO correctly. Try instead to let your clk2 logic always set `rd_en` when AFIFO is `!empty`.

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot of my simulations with AFIFO.

Comment: Quite a few things look a bit strange in that image. First I would say that the delay you are seeing is much larger than what I would expect. Six slow clock cycles seems excessive. This may be something that is controllable in the FIFO generator.
Secondly, `empty` and `data_out` don't seem to be synchronous to clk2, but rather it is delayed by 1/4 cycle. This may however be simulated delay, and also part of the FIFO generator.
Finally, you are still enabling `rd_en` when it should not be enabled. `rd_en` should never be high as long as `empty` is high.

Comment: I have uploaded the second screenshot too in which rd_en is activated when AFIFO is !empty. Now I am getting wrong first value at data_out!! Along with the following warnings when I simulate:                                               Error: C:/Xilinx/verilog/src/simprims/X_RAMB16_S36_S36.v(2655): $setup( posedge DIA[1] &&& dia_enable:127784 ps, posedge CLKA:127972 ps, 484 ps );
#    Time: 127972 ps  Iteration: 3  Instance: /tb/uut/\AFIFO1/BU2/U0/grf.rf/mem/gbm.gbmg.gbmga.ngecc.bmg/blk_mem_generator/valid.cstr/ramloop[0].ram.r/v2_noinit.ram/dp36x36.ram\

Comment: I have uploaded the second screenshot too in which rd_en is activated when AFIFO is !empty. Now I am getting wrong first value at data_out!! Along with the following warnings when I simulate:                                               Error: C:/Xilinx/verilog/src/simprims/X_RAMB16_S36_S36.v(2655): $setup( posedge DIA[1] &&& dia_enable:127784 ps, posedge CLKA:127972 ps, 484 ps );
#    Time: 127972 ps  Iteration: 3  Instance: /tb/uut/\AFIFO1/BU2/U0/grf.rf/mem/gbm.gbmg.gbmga.ngecc.bmg/blk_mem_generator/valid.cstr/ramloop[0].ram.r/v2_noinit.ram/dp36x36.ram\

Comment: Not only does `rd_en` need to be set only when `!empty` but it must also be synchronous to `clk2`. The setup errors that you are seeing are very likely due to the asynchronous asserting of `rd_en`. $setup errors are related to the metastability which i mentioned earlier. I see now that your `clk2` always block is clocked on `negedge`. This is probably not supported by AFIFO. Try `posedge` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to transform some data synchronous to clk1 to synchronous to clk2 by a asynchronous FIFO.

First of all,you do not need to sample signal synchronous to clk1 by clk2 directly.Like using wr_en which is generated by clk1 to control rd_en which is clocked by clk2.It will cause metastability.FIFO is always used to solve the problem of metastability.So no need to do as the second always block.

So problem is become to how to use asynchronous FIFO correctly.
You should read Xilinx FIFO generator product guide like PG057.You should know FIFO's theory and usage method.Otherwise you will have a lot of pain when using FIFO.

My advise is below.
For write operation,you need to use both almost_full and full signal to avoid overflow.You can see it in PG057 figure 3-2.You need to use almost_full,because if wr_en is continous then full signal is 1 clock slower to aviod overflow. 
For read operation,you need to use both almost_empty and empty signal,as the same reason.
Then you can transform the clock region correctly.

Forgive my English.